# Is the opposite of 'within', 'without'?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, antonyms

Typically *without* is used to mean *not having something*.

E.g.

> He went to work without his pants on.

However, I'm wondering if it can be used for *outside the bounds of*.

We do this with *within.* For example:

> Please keep your children within the bounds of the school.

So could the following:

> The vigilante was operating *without* the bounds of the law (or)
>
> The shop refused to refund my item, as it was *without* the warranty period.

be viewed as being acceptable?

Comment: Neat question, I don't know if that's an archaic usage, or, if it's never in history been used that way.  The enemy within.  The enemy without.....

Comment: Quoth the Beatles: “…when you see we’re all one and life flows on within you and without you…”

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That usage, and other similar songs of the era, make equal sense with the word taken in the other sense as a pun. "Life flows on in your absence."

Comment: That was exactly its usage in the medieval period. The City of London Church [Saint Botolph without Bishopsgate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Botolph-without-Bishopsgate) was so named because it was just outside the City gate. There were also two wards called Bridge Within and [Bridge Without](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28ward%29) and even a children's book [The Battle of Saint George without](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Battle-George-without-Puffin-Books/dp/0140310118).

Comment: @Potatoswatter You’ll note I didn’t say whether the Beatles quote speaks for or against _without_ as a semantic antonym to _within_. It does show that _without_ can be used as a **formal** antonym (i.e., a word juxtaposed with an obviously opposite form, regardless of meaning), like “They fought bravely within the city walls, but without help”.

Comment: Modern Scots has a solution to this conundrum, we use 'outwith' for this usage. People here would readily understand  'The shop refused to refund my item, as it was *outwith* the warranty period.' as meaning the speaker was refused because the warranty had expired.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "within" have an antonym? If so, what?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11166/does-within-have-an-antonym-if-so-what)

Answer (score 7):

It appears that it can also be used in that sense, though less common.

[without](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Without)

- On the outside: a sturdy structure **within and without.**

The Online Etymology Dictionary has reference to your issue.

> [**without**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Without&searchmode=none) (adv., prep.)  Old English wiðutan "outside of, from
>   outside," literally "against the outside" (*opposite of within*),
>   see **with** + **out** (adv.). As a word expressing lack or want of
>   something (opposite of *with*), attested from c.1200. In use by late
>   14c. as a conjunction, short for **without that**.
>
> [**within**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Within&searchmode=none) (adv., prep.)  Old English *wiðinnan* "within, from within",
>   literally "against the inside", see **with** + **in**.

Comment: I don't agree with this.  If at one time it was acceptable doesn't mean you can use it now.  If I wrote the set of sentences using without, I would at best look ignorant or a non-native speaker, really I would just confuse people.  The word is outside - it's not confusing and it is common usage.

Comment: It is not used these days. Even the references you have mentioned are from Old English. The word doesn't give any meaning to the statements mentioned in the question.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd Agreed, today we would say "outside", but Josh61 is answering the title of the question. Is *within* the opposite of *without*? And the reply is a tentative "yes".

Comment: Commonly we use _outside_ but not [always](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22within+and+*+without%22)

Comment: One needs to be very careful using it in the sense of "outside" in order to avoid confusion; it is almost always seen in recent writing (even in recent writing that is meant to seem archaic, as in fantasy or period fiction) as the last word in a sentence for that reason: *The doors were oaken within and brazen without.* A reader unaccustomed to the usage might want to ask "without what?", but cannot be nearly as confused as if the answer to that question *seemed* to be in the sentence already.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hymn that starts with the words, "There is a green hill far away, Without a city wall."  Here the word without clearly means the opposite of within.  It is archaic but it certainly used to be used in this sense.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! What an interesting answer. Can you provide any sources?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, without can mean *lacking* / *absence of* OR *outside*.

> *Without* is a broader term, covering both *lacking* and *the absence of,* and also means *outside.* (This double meaning led to the Marx Brothers routine: *There's a girl waiting without.* *Without what?* *Without food or clothing.* *Well, feed her and send her in.*)

[Source](https://www.nytimes.com/1982/03/28/magazine/the-present-absent-on-language.html). Safire, William. A version of this article appears in print on March 28, 1982, Section 6, Page 10 of the (NYT) National edition with the headline: *The Present Absent On Language*.

Answer (score 0):

In Scottish English (not dialect or Lowland Scots) the term is:

**Outwith**

Which as an Englishman I had never encountered until I moved to Glasgow, where I found it used in academic circles.

You will find it in Chambers Dictionary (not online but on the iPhone app) where it is defined as:

> *preposition* (Scot) outside of

> *adverb* outwards

Answer (score -4):

No, we cannot use without as opposite of within or as holding a meaning 'outside the bounds of'. It can't be used for that purpose.

They are not antonyms of each other.

Comment: "Wamba had improved their town and made it a fair and comfortable place to dwell in, and the barbarians without the gates were quieted now by frequent defeat." ~ ~ Does this sentence mean the barbarians outside the gates, or the barbarians who didn't own a single gate between them?

Comment: Here, it means the barbarians who weren't stopped by any gates.

Comment: You really think so? ~ ~ "archaic or literary - Outside:
'the barbarians without the gates' -> http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/without

Answer (score -4):

*Without* is the (negative) antonym of *with*, and that's the end of that story.

*Within* means inside, and the (opposite) antonym would be *outside*. (This fits "the bounds of the law" or "the warranty period.")

**EDIT:** Others have suggested that your proposed usage, while archaic, is still correct. Beware the distinction of negative vs. opposite:

- "Without the bounds of the law" would imply that the law was not bounding him, or inapplicable, not that he was dodging it.
- "Without the warranty period" would imply that there was never any warranty, not that it had lapsed.

The usage you suggest does not exist in modern English. It is incorrect in your examples.

Comment: When changing your answer after receiving a lot of downvotes, I'd recommend deleting the answer, and reposting.